# How to access child of recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

On the chat app I'm creating there are multiple audios. I need the childview in following case:

1) Guess you are playing one audio.(Play button will change to Pause) Now during that you are playing second audio.(For first audio Pause button should change to Play and For second audio Play button will change to Pause)

So how to access the first view button when user pressing second audio play button.

Thanks is advance !!

[ChatActivity.java](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6sd_GBkPcq7cGo4OXNsbVhGMDA)

[ChatAdapter.java](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6sd_GBkPcq7dVhnLTF1a21LNWM)

Comment: you have to put indicator for the view that is playing , like setPlayingView(int position) , and when you change the playing before you  you set the new playing get the current playing and change it then get the new one and so on , make sure to call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Im having position when audio is being played. Now when next audio plays. How to access old view from adapter ?

Comment: here an example for your scenario , 
lets say you have 4 views 
lets create setter and getter for the current playing 
lets play the first item when you click play check if there is playing item in the getter if so go to the item of that position and change it and call notifydata set change , then set the new position and change it and call the method again

Comment: @DhawalRathod Show some code. There are a variety of ways to do this, if you show your implementation of the `RecyclerView` and `Adapter` we can assist you better.

Comment: @Bryan Have look at code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the answer by my own. I'm posting for future reference.

Saving last `imageView` as `ivLastClicked` in one variable and then when new button clicked again assign it to `ivLastClicked` before that change background and save the clicked to `ivLastClicked` variable.

Answer (score 1):

If your list never change, you can access it by using [CustomClickListener](https://gist.github.com/riyazMuhammad/1c7b1f9fa3065aa5a46f) for RecyclerView.

Create a variable to hold current play position. Then in your implemented CustomItemClickListener, check if there is a played song. If there, change to pause. If not just play the song. Here a snippet:

```
private int mPlayedSongItemId = 0; // no played song
private Adapter mAdapter;
...
...
mAdapter = new YourAdapter(getActivity(), data, new CustomItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
     if(mPlayedSongItemId != 0) {
     // change old play button to play
     // change current play button to pause        
     }
   }
   });
```

That code will not run of course. You should adapt it to your need. Try changing *position* to *ViewHolder* in CustomClickListener interface.